# Using Python, how can I group 40,000 data sets (by the criteria listed below) in a table with 5 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table with 5 columns and 40,000 rows. Below is a section of the table.

```
             device_type           x      y        z       time
0   jg4M/taYRc2cBJfGa8c8vw==    3796.3  -137.2  5114.6  00:12:32
1   jg4M/thYRc2cBfPGa8c8vw==    3796.7  -137.2  5114.2  00:12:32
2   jg4M/taYRc2cBbPGa8c8vw==    3796.7  -137.2  5114.2  00:12:32
3   chIM3a44QxdtbmgjyBFGDQ==    4009.9  -6.8    4950.7  00:12:59
4   PdhyfpkIT8Weslf54thwuQ==    3966.3  8.0     4985.7  00:12:34
```

I used this code:

```
DF23 = DF21.groupby('device_type').count()
```

To get the following table:

```
                            x   y   z   time
        device_type
++GbLXzbQTyASMveP6QJXQ==    23  23  23  23
++HbQkXsTFWuLwbQccXDxw==    6   6   6   6          : : : 
++0mTDG3T0C3b5ty2fEyIQ==    2   2   2   2
++2jKi0KRp2Uh6nhj6NHTw==    3   3   3   3
++3LoRZFTfaUjDjbR5FdsA==    3   3   3   3
                         :
                         :
```

This table has 40,000 data sets, however there is only around 18000 'device_type' data sets.

This means that, for example, under the device_type:

```
++GbLXzbQTyASMveP6QJXQ==
```

There are 23 different x,y,z and time data.

How can I group and show all of the data sets under each device_type instead of just counting how many there are?

I want to get a similar result to the following which shows all the data under device_type 0, then device_type 1 etc.:

```
       device_type                x         y     z       time
0   jg4M/taYRc2cBJfGa8c8vw==    3796.3  -137.2  5114.6  00:12:32
                                3796.7  -137.2  5114.2  00:12:32
                                3796.7  -137.2  5114.2  00:12:32
                                4009.9  -6.8    4950.7  00:12:59
                                3966.3  8.0     4985.7  00:12:34
1   PdhyfpkIT8Weslf54thwuQ==    4564.3  335.66  4563.5  00:12:56
                                4578.9  -452.3  5535.6  00:12:56
                                   :
                                   :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are curious, this is the right code:

DF23 = DF21.groupby(['device_type','time','x','y','z']).count()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use aggregation as you did, just use this:

```
DF23 = DF21.groupby('device_type')
for key,group in DF23:
     print(DF23.get_group(key),"\n")
```